# Linux Mint 17.3: Screen freezes all the time

Tags: linux-mint

The new Linux Mint .iso I installed on my computer yesterday. I updated the system and used dist-upgrade too. I installed Chromium-Browser; afterwards I tried to install texlive-full. And then: screen freeze. I restarted my computer, but I had the same problem afterwards. Screen freeze.

I googled it, and I could see that a lot of other users had the same problem with Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa with Cinammon.

PS! My system is encrypted. Could that be the problem?

Comment: And none of those other users that **had** the problem, and no longer have it, described how to resolve it? Have you tried to ask someone that obviously got rid of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Using two Linux Operating Systems. Linux Mint 17.3 and Linux Mint 18.1. When scrolling a web page with Mozilla Firefox, latest version, I experience a freeze. Can still see web page but nothing functions. Cursor , keyboard, all frozen. Only solution is to shut PC down with power button. This temporarily solves problem which returns again in short amount of time. Tried many suggestions at various forums to no avail. Problem persisted.

My solution which worked for me is as follows:

1. Open Firefox.
2. Click on three horizontal lies at upper right of page.
3. Click on "Preferences"
4. Click on 'Advanced"
5. Click on "General" tab
6. At bottom of page uncheck the four boxes under "Browsing"
    They read: - Use auto scrolling
               - Use smooth scrolling
               - Use hardware acceleration
               - Check your spelling.......

If this works for you let others know.

My apologies for giving the wrong info the first time around. My only excuse is - up too late, half asleep...